# Django query returning multiple users instead of one

Tags: django

On my dashboard I'm querying a profile model that has a one to one relationship with user model. But instead of getting one user since there is only one profile per user, I'm getting all users in the database and one profile. I could probably work around the issue but from a security perspective I'm concerned about somehow getting all users from database. I checked the database fields and everything is OK so problem is with the code. Here's the code:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
  lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
 if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   instance.profile.save()
```

Here's the code for form:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
    model = Profile
    exclude = ['afield', 'anotherfield']
    labels = {
        'user': _('User Name'),
        'firstname': _('First Name'),
        'lastname': _('Last Name'),
        'city': _('City'),
```

Here's the view:

```
@login_required
def buy_subscription(request):
 if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
            form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/mypage.html', {'form': form})
else:
    return redirect("login/")
```

Template is standard:

```
{% for field in form %}
{% render_field field  class="form-control" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here's what I'm getting on the html side:

```
<select name="user" class="form-control" required id="id_user">
<option value="">---------</option>
<option value="61">User1</option>
<option value="62">User2</option>
<option value="63" selected>User3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing a field that allows you to change that OneToOneField's value to another user. (Changing it would probably fail, though, if all users already have profiles.)

Add

```
exclude = ['user']
```

to the `ProfileForm` to avoid having that field there.

I would additionally suggest looking into custom user models instead of the older one-to-one profile model technique, for added performance and less headaches :)